# Android Boilepipe - java.lang.RuntimeException

Tags: java, android

I am using boilerpipe-android library I downloaded from https://github.com/BartoszJarocki/boilerpipe-android 
It works great when I'm in debugging mode, but when I compile release version I'm getting an error.

This is the error

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground() 
           at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
           at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
           at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner.scanEntityRef(HTMLScanner.java:1386)
           at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scanAttribute(HTMLScanner.java:2955)
           at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scanAttribute(HTMLScanner.java:2785)
           at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scanStartElement(HTMLScanner.java:2639)
           at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scan(HTMLScanner.java:2071)
           at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner.scanDocument(HTMLScanner.java:891)
           at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:491)
           at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:444)
           at mf.org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:109)
           at mf.org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1199)
           at de.l3s.boilerpipe.sax.BoilerpipeSAXInput.getTextDocument(BoilerpipeSAXInput.java:61)
           at de.l3s.boilerpipe.sax.BoilerpipeSAXInput.getTextDocument(BoilerpipeSAXInput.java:49)
           at de.l3s.boilerpipe.sax.ImageExtractor.process(ImageExtractor.java:109)
           at com.ulicast.Feed.ImageLinkExtractor.doInBackground(ImageLinkExtractor.java:43)
           at com.ulicast.Feed.ImageLinkExtractor.doInBackground(ImageLinkExtractor.java:22)
           at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
           at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: in == null
          at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:246)
          at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLEntities.load0(HTMLEntities.java:102)
          at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLEntities.(HTMLEntities.java:54)
          at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner.scanEntityRef(HTMLScanner.java:1386) 
          at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scanAttribute(HTMLScanner.java:2955) 
          at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scanAttribute(HTMLScanner.java:2785) 
          at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scanStartElement(HTMLScanner.java:2639) 
          at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scan(HTMLScanner.java:2071) 
          at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner.scanDocument(HTMLScanner.java:891) 
          at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:491) 
          at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:444) 
          at mf.org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:109) 
          at mf.org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1199) 
          at de.l3s.boilerpipe.sax.BoilerpipeSAXInput.getTextDocument(BoilerpipeSAXInput.java:61) 
          at de.l3s.boilerpipe.sax.BoilerpipeSAXInput.getTextDocument(BoilerpipeSAXInput.java:49) 
          at de.l3s.boilerpipe.sax.ImageExtractor.process(ImageExtractor.java:109) 
          at com.ulicast.Feed.ImageLinkExtractor.doInBackground(ImageLinkExtractor.java:43) 
          at com.ulicast.Feed.ImageLinkExtractor.doInBackground(ImageLinkExtractor.java:22) 
          at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295) 
          at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
          at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

And here is the class I'm using to fetch the data.

```
public class ImageLinkExtractor extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

private ImageLinkExtractorListener listener;

public ImageLinkExtractor (ImageLinkExtractorListener listener){
    this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    listener.onExecuteFinish(s);
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String url = params[0];
    String image = null;
    final BoilerpipeExtractor extractor = ArticleExtractor.getInstance();
    final ImageExtractor ie = ImageExtractor.getInstance();

    try {
        List<Image> imgUrls = ie.process(new URL(url), extractor);
        Collections.sort(imgUrls);
        if(!imgUrls.isEmpty()) image = imgUrls.get(0).getSrc();
    } catch (IOException | SAXException | BoilerpipeProcessingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return image;
}

public interface ImageLinkExtractorListener{
    void onExecuteFinish(String imageUrl);
}
```

}

From the class where I call this AsyncTask I call it like this

```
new ImageLinkExtractor(new ImageLinkExtractor.ImageLinkExtractorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onExecuteFinish(String imageUrl) {
                    if(imageUrl!=null) {
                        post.setLinkImage(imageUrl);
                        holder.linkLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.linkImage.setImageUrl(imageUrl, AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader());
                    }
                }
            }).execute(post.getLink());
```

Comment: Anyone downvoting, care to give out the reason? What is wrong with my question?

Comment: They down vote due to question is related to help with library.

Comment: @karan being a library doesn't make the question invalid. I have tried asking on github as well. People ask here questions on google/facebook APIs all the time, this one is no different.

Comment: its like if you are caught. and reviewed by them. then your question is against rules. And buddy I have not down voted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely that this is due to a library class using reflection and the class names are obfuscated/minified with proguard on the release build. Since the class name has changed, the reflection string doesn't match the class name any more and causes the crash.

To get more clues you could add this to your project's proguard file

```
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
```

That should at least get you file name and lines in the stack traces instead of *Unknown Source*, which might give you more clues.

Maybe adding this line to your project proguard file will fix things:

```
-keep class org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser
```

Comment: Thanks! It finally works, I've tried to just keep all the classes related to the file, at first my syntax was wrong I guess, this one worked "-keep class de.l3s.**
-keep class org.cyberneko.**
-keep class org.apache.xerces.**"